# URL nomenclature: Naming a certain part of an URL

Tags: uri, domain-name, nomenclature

I just can't get my head around a handy term to name the beginning part of an URI:

```
http://sub.domain.com/ ...
```

The official nomenclature of the various parts of my URI example is well known to me (protocol/scheme, host name made up of subdomain, domain name and tld ... you name it). But what would I call both, scheme and host name combined?

My best bet so far would be `base URI`.
What's yours?

Comment: URNs don't have a "host", so you may want to restrict your question further.

Comment: Ok, let's narrow it down to URLs instead. Any clue?

Comment: your question is better suited elsewhere.